# Resteasy async API report progress and remaining time/ETA

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have more or less successfully implemented an async POST based on Resteasy's 
[Asynchronous Job Service](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/async_job_service.html)
but I find it very short-sighted if I cannot also provide a client with more information on the async task - i.e. progress % and estimated remaining time of the operation, is there any way to do just that?